# Pull data in from firestore with React

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

From my understanding, if i use the code below to retrieve what i have in firestore, it should be an array. I tried

```
data.forEach((doc) => {
  console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
});
```

standard example code from google firestore. I found the object in console log is the array i need to get from the db.

Now, this is my code

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { getDocs, collection } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { db } from '../firebase-config';


const Home = () => {

    const [postList, setPostList] = useState([]);
    const postsCollectionRef = collection(db, "data");

    useEffect(() => {
        const getPosts = async () => {
            const data = await getDocs(postsCollectionRef);
            data.forEach((doc) => {
                setPostList({ ...doc.data() });
            });
        };
        getPosts();
        console.log(postList);
    }, []);


    return (
        <div>{postList[0].Example}</div>
    );
};

export default Home;
```

why it returns an empty array?

[image]

Comment: can you provide the whole code, of your component, I would like to know about how you are using useState Hook for setPostList.

Comment: I am new to this. The return statement is just a draft I tentatively put it on. I have some mapping to do in the return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call

```
setPostList({ ...doc.data() });
```

It will overwrite the old state, so what you would need to do is to create an array from Firestore data and then set that whole array inside of state like below

```
    useEffect(() => {
    const getPosts = async () => {
        const data = await getDocs(postsCollectionRef);
        let postListArray = []
        data.forEach((doc) => {
            const post = { ...doc.data() } 
            postListArray.push(post)
        });
        setPostList(postListArray)
    };
    getPosts();
    console.log(postList);
}, []);
```

Comment: If this answer works for you, can you mark this as an accepted Answer?

Comment: I think i have a problem, it worked. But It don't work now. Any idea how?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) with [`snapshot.docs`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot) (array of `DocumentSnapshots`) as shown below:

```
const snapshot = await getDocs(postsCollectionRef);

const data = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({ id: doc.id, ...d.data() }))

setPostList(data);
```

Comment: Thanks man, this works too. Since Mr. Daswani started the conversation with me first. I marked his, given the priority.